# What is the difference between `import Anything from #anywhere` and no import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

When using [autoimport feature of nuxt3](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/concepts/auto-imports/#explicit-imports):

- is there any impact (types, performance, bundle-size, tree-shaking, etc..) of using the `#` alias to import something rather than no import at all?
- Or its only purpose is to make imports explicit and maybe help to fix some IDE/linter/ts issues?

Example:

```js
// plugins/vuetify.ts
import { createVuetify, VuetifyOptions } from "vuetify";
import { defineNuxtPlugin, NuxtApp, Plugin } from "#app"; // this line should be optional

export const VuetifyPlugin: Plugin = defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp: NuxtApp) => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify();

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify);
});

export default VuetifyPlugin;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware of the `#` import, do you have a reference for that specifc one?

As you kinda guessed it, there are no direct benefits of making the imports yourself. In the same way that Nuxt does the job for you regarding `ref, computed, watch` etc, it will try to import most of the other common stuff.

The compiler will scan your file, see what you are using in your template + script part and make the import himself on runtime. It may not guess fully dynamic imports (usually for components based on a dynamic variable for example).

Still, it should work in the exact same way performance-wise.

For the types I know that there could be some limitations (not a full coverage), but since I don't use TS, I'm not well aware of all the details.

Regarding IDEs/code editors, most of the time they will work fine but some of them may require a bit of configuration to work perfectly (since it's implicit, you still need to tell your editor what is happening), otherwise some Linters may complain a bit.

Nuxt's auto import feature is probably based on something really similar (if not identical) to this: https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-auto-import
Hence, you can see in details how this one works to get more explanation.

Comment: thanks for reply, for the reference, the only one i found is the one linked in the question